# Can zoom functionality be implemented in the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, accessibility

Most iOS apps allow zooming capabilities with two fingers via the touch screen. For the most part, I don't think this is all that big of a deal for the Stack Exchange app; however, I just found myself wishing that I could zoom in on a picture that someone had uploaded as part of their answer, so I'm wondering if it would be possible to implement zooming capabilities in the iOS app for the (possibly rare but nonetheless existent) situations in which users might wish that they could zoom in on content in the app.

Comment: By the way, if you tap on a photo that's part of a question or an answer, it will open it on its own. Then you'll be able to zoom into it.